# Gaussian Process Regression with independent variable uncertainty on datapoints

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, uncertainty, error-propagation

Imagine that I have a set of $N$ (training) datapoints $\left\{(x_n,y_n)\right\}_{n=1}^N$, with error bars/uncertainties on *each* datapoint along *both* the $x$- and $y$-directions, written as $\left\{(\sigma_{x,n},\sigma_{y,n})\right\}_{n=1}^N$, that may not be the same between datapoints. See the image below from [Hogg et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4686) for an example of such a dataset (ignore the dotted lines).

[image]

My question is: is there anything in the Gaussian Process literature that deals with fitting a GP to such a 2-D uncertainty dataset? I'm confused about where the addition of the $x$ uncertainties would factor in; the covariance function? Should we also model additive noise in the $x$ direction as well, if the scatter along $x$ cannot solely be attributed to the error bars?

Comment: Do you have a particular problem in mind? Can you say something about the uncertainty in $x_i$ in a probabilistic way? e.g. $x_i \sim U(l_i, u_i)$ or $x \sim N(m_i, v_i)$?